# Placement of logo and putting text on it in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2, eso-pic

I would like to compose a header for the `scrlttr2` class where my logo spans the top, but I need to be able to write into that logo. This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% header picture on first page

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \hspace*{1in}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1in]{example-image-a}
    }%
  }
}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \hspace*{3cm}%
    \raisebox{5.5cm}{
        \parbox{3cm}{
                \scriptsize
                \textbf{THIS}\\[.2em]
                \textbf{IS}\\[.2em]
                \textbf{MY}\\[.2em]
                \textbf{LOGO}
        }}
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \raisebox{3cm}{
    \parbox{0.2\hsize}{%
        \scriptsize
        \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
        \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\\
        \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\\[1em]
    }}%
}


% sender

\setkomavar{fromname}{Aaron Berentsen}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ceestreet 1\\Deetown}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+12345678}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+12345679}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{ab@c.de}

% date

\setkomavar{date}{\today}

% subject

\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Addressee}

    \opening{Dear Addresse,}
    \lipsum[1]
    \closing{Best wishes,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

However I want to align the (centered) logo such that its left edge aligns with the address box and I want to lower it down such that it leaves the default header space from the top (roughly indicated by the red annotations).

According to the Koma guide, the top space seems to be `firstheadvpos`, the left indent should be `firstheadhpos`, and the width of the image to cover the head should be `fromrulewidth`. But I did not manage to find out how to use those lengths.

I used the `eso-pic` class in order to be able to write onto the logo image itself, which is also a requirement. Probably I need to replace the lengths in

- `\raisebox{-\height-\useplength{firstheadvpos}}` and
- `\hspace*{\useplength{firstheadhpos}}` and
- `\includegraphics[width=\useplength{fromrulewidth},...`

but that doesn't seem to be how that works. Any advice?

**Edit:** just to clarify: I used the `eso-pic` in order to be able to write onto the logo, so that already works. My question is just how to use the pseudo lengths to tell iso-pic how to position it such that it fits right on the header area (same position, same size), that is that it has the same top and left margin and the same width.

Comment: What did you do in the end? (When you answer, please start answer with @Keks + TAB)

Comment: @KeksDose I used the `\showfields` command to see the outline of the header and positioned the logo as above by hand/eye. Felt this was much more straight forward than the other options and still good enough. The code was `\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
\AtPageUpperLeft{
\raisebox{-1.4\height}{
\hspace*{0.78in}
\includegraphics[width=\useplength{firstheadwidth}]{picture.png}}}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use package `scrlayer` and define a new page style that positions the picture at the desired place using pseudolengths:

```latex
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  voffset=\useplength{firstheadvpos},
  hoffset=\useplength{toaddrhpos},
  width=\useplength{firstheadwidth},
  contents={\includegraphics[width=\layerwidth,height=1in]{example-image-a}}
]{firstheadpicture}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{firstheadpicture}
```

The first letter page uses page style `empty` by default. I would patch `\opening` to overwrite this default page style:

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\opening{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

`fromemail` etc. should go to the location field:

```latex
\setkomavar{location}{\scriptsize
  \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
}
\setplength[.2]{locwidth}{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}% <- change the width of location to the desired value
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

%% to show the position of first head and location:
  %\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
  %\showfields{head,location}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

% picture in the background of first head
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  voffset=\useplength{firstheadvpos},
  hoffset=\useplength{toaddrhpos},
  width=\useplength{firstheadwidth},
  contents={\includegraphics[width=\layerwidth,height=1in]{example-image-a}}
]{firstheadpicture}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{firstheadpicture}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\opening{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}{}{\PatchFailed}

% first head
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \vskip .5cm%
  \noindent\hspace*{3cm}%
    \parbox{3cm}{\scriptsize\bfseries
      THIS\\[.2em]
      IS\\[.2em]
      MY\\[.2em]
      LOGO
    }
}

% location
\setkomavar{location}{\scriptsize
  \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
}
\setplength[.2]{locwidth}{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}% <- change the width of location to the desired value

% sender
\setkomavar{fromname}{Aaron Berentsen}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ceestreet 1\\Deetown}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+12345678}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+12345679}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{ab@c.de}

% date
%\setkomavar{date}{\today}% default

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Addressee}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}% maybe you write more than one letter with different subjects in this document
\opening{Dear Addresse,}
  \lipsum
  \closing{Best wishes,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could use

```latex
 \LoadLetterOption{visualize}
 \showfields{head,location}% address, foot and refline are also possible
```

in the preamble to show the position of `head` and `location`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Coding a new letterhead isn't that easy. Maybe we can ignore the idea of a "firsthead" (`firsthead=off`) and put the elements on the page manually.

```
\documentclass[firsthead=off]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum, picture, calc, booktabs}

% header picture on first page

\newlength{\xlength}
\newlength{\ylength}
\setlength{\xlength}{20mm}
\setlength{\ylength}{-40mm}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \put(\xlength, \ylength){
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth + 20mm,height=1in]{example-image-a}}
    \put(\xlength,.5\ylength){
                  \scriptsize\textbf{~This is my logo}
                }
                \put(\xlength,\ylength+2\baselineskip){%
                  \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
                    Even a & tabular\\
                    may & follow!\\\bottomrule
                  \end{tabular}
                }
  }
}

\addtoplength{firstheadvpos}{-.3\ylength}
\addtoplength{locvpos}{5cm}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Aaron Berentsen}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ceestreet 1\\Deetown}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+12345678}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+12345679}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{ab@c.de}

\setkomavar{location}{%
        \scriptsize
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \usekomavar*{fromphone}&\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
        \usekomavar*{fromfax}&\usekomavar{fromfax}\\
        \usekomavar*{fromemail}&\usekomavar{fromemail}\\[1em]
        \end{tabular}
}



% sender


% date

\setkomavar{date}{\today}

% subject

\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Addressee}

    \opening{Dear Addresse,}
    \lipsum[1]
    \closing{Best wishes,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: letter picture]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I fully understand the issue, but you can use `\stackinset` to overlay text on the image.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum,stackengine}

% header picture on first page

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \hspace*{1in}%
    \stackinset{r}{.8in}{c}{0in}{\parbox{1in}{\scriptsize
              \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
        \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\\
        \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}}}{%
    \stackinset{l}{1in}{c}{0in}{\parbox{1in}{\scriptsize\bfseries
      THIS\\IS\\MY\\LOGO}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1in]{example-image-a}%
    }}%
    }%
  }%
}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{}


% sender

\setkomavar{fromname}{Aaron Berentsen}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ceestreet 1\\Deetown}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+12345678}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+12345679}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{ab@c.de}

% date

\setkomavar{date}{\today}

% subject

\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Addressee}

    \opening{Dear Addresse,}
    \lipsum[1]
    \closing{Best wishes,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]